# For S.O.C. of constrained optimization problem, why need a bordered hessian?

Tags: matrices, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, hessian-matrix

If we have a constrained optimization problem
$$\max_xf(x_1,...,x_n), \text {s.t.} g(x_1, ...,x_n)=0$$
Then we can use Lagrange's theorem and use these as first order conditions, to find the critical points of the lagrangian.

But I am now reading that as Second order conditions for a maximum we need:
$$v^TD^2L(x^*, \lambda ^*)v<0, \forall (v\neq 0)\in \mathbb R^n \text {for which } Dg(x^*)v=0$$

My lecture notes then go on to say that to find points that satisfy this  condition, we need to construct the **"bordered Hessian"**, and check the sign of the "last n-m" leading principal minors.

I have two questions:

1. Is there an intuitive explanation for why this condition on the bordered hessian implies that the S.O.C. for a maximum is met? How does it relate to positive definiteness of the bordered hessian for example?
2. Are there other ways to check whether these conditions are met? e.g. can we also check the eigenvalues of the bordered hessian ?

Comment: Is $g : R^n \to R^m$ ?

Comment: Yes, but I usually assume $m=1$ for simplicity.

Comment: The subspace $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which $Dg(x^*)v = 0$, is the kernel of $D(g^*)$. It corresponds to the **tangent space** to the constraint set. The inequality $v^T D^2 L(x^*,\lambda^*)v < 0$ says that the quadratic form given by $D^2L(...)$ is *negative definite* on that tangent space, which informally corresponds to being "concave down" ($y=-x^2$ has negative derivative; in unconstrained optimization, the [ordinary] Hessian being negative definite corresponds to maximum). ... To pass to eigenvalues, might need to decompose matrix first, into blocks for the tangent space and normal?

Comment: @zach-Teiler, so that is why the matrix needs to be positive definite on the tangent space. That I find intuitive. But why is that positive definiteness implied by the conditions on the "bordered hessian". How do we even interpret this "bordered" hessian

Comment: @zach-teitler, sorry miss spelled your name

Comment: Hmm, hopefully someone who knows better will step in. It seems to me that the bordered Hessian is the matrix representing the inner product on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we don't need it to be negative or positive definite on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, rather on just the kernel of the first derivative map. ... I know you have some lecture notes you're following, but in case additional notes might be helpful, I thought these seemed decent: http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~clark/285/2006-07/handouts/lagrange-2deriv.pdf.

Comment: @ZachTeitler, Thank you. I will look at these notes over the week.